# jQuery UI Dialog opening partial view (.ascx)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I am a little confused on how to open a partial view inside of a jquery UI Dialog window.  I was doing it with simple Dialog but for various reasons, I decided to go in a different direction.  All the tutorials online are just opening `<div></div>`'s and that's fine, but I need to open an entire ascx file...  BTW I plan on having jquery validation and jquery UI Datepickers inside this partial view.

Any example's or tutorials that you guys know of?

Thanks,
I can provide some of my sample code if you guys need it.

**UPDATE: More details plus code**
This would indeed be an MVC partial view.  Some code of what I tried previously follows this sentence...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .load('<%:Html.ActionLink("edit", "EditTemplate", "PatientACO", new { Template = int.Parse(patId), popID = populationId}, new {@class = "tempDlg", title = "Edit Patient Info"})%>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Edit Patient ACO information'
    });
    });
```

That is my jQuery Code...

```
    %><%:Html.ActionLink("edit", "EditTemplate", "PatientACO", new { Template = int.Parse(patId), popID = populationId}, new {@class = "tempDlg", title = "Edit Patient Info"})%><%
```

That would be the EditTemplate is the name of the view (which loads a partial view if it is a javascript request a reqular view if not)

**More Code to help others see what is going on**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $('a.tempDlg').live("click", function(event) {loadDialog(this, event, '#edit-set');});
    $('a.AddPatDlg').live("click", function(event) {loadDialog(this, event, '#addPat');});
    $('a.AcoData').live("click", function(event) {loadDialog(this, event, '#addEncounter');});


}); /* end document.ready() */

function loadDialog(tag, event, target) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $loading = $('<img src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/images/ajaxLoading.gif")%>" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
    var $url = $(tag).attr('href');
    var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
    $dialog.empty();
    $dialog
        .append($loading)
        .load($url)
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false
                        , title: $title
                        , width: 950
            , modal: true
                        , minHeight: 200
            , show: 'fade'
            , hide: 'fade'
                });

    $dialog.dialog("option", "buttons", { "Cancel": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close"); $(this).empty();
    },
        "Submit": function () {
            var dlg = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: $url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#target").serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    $(target).html(response);
                    dlg.dialog('close');
                    dlg.empty();
                    $("#ajaxResult").hide().html('Record saved').fadeIn(300, function () {
                        var e = this;
                        setTimeout(function () { $(e).fadeOut(400); }, 2500);
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    if (xhr.status == 400)
                        dlg.html(xhr.responseText, xhr.status);     /* display validation errors in edit dialog */
                    else
                        displayError(xhr.responseText, xhr.status); /* display other errors in separate dialog */

                }
            });
        }
    });     

    $dialog.dialog('open');
};

function displayError(message, status)
{
    var $dialog = $(message);
        $dialog
            .dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: status + ' Error',
            buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    }); 
    return false;             
};
    // jQuery Ajax-Post only works in repeatable manner when link that opens SimpleDialog can be placed 
    // outside the PartialView. Otherwise, calls to SimpleDialog fail on second and subsequent clicks. 
    // Need to use full postback in this case.
    $("#btnSubmit").live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(this).attr("name");
        var $url = $("#target").attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#target").serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                $.simpleDialog.close();
                $($target).html(response);
                $("#ajaxResult").hide().html('Record saved.').fadeIn(300, function () {
                    var e = this;
                    setTimeout(function () { $(e).fadeOut(400); }, 2000);
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                $("#ajaxResult").html(xhr.responseText).show();
                $.simpleDialog.close();
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        tableToGrid("#table1", { shrinkToFit: false, width: 1000 });
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean an mvc partial view or an asp.net user control?

Comment: Post the sample code of what you have tried.

Comment: please reformat and extend your code postings for us to have better understanding how you have it now...Essentially what you should do is point JQuery UI dialog at a controller action which returns 'return PartialView(...)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always done it like this. It may be a bit long-winded but it's easy to read and debug...

Just create an empty div on your page and give it an Id.

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

Then in your JS you can make an ajax call to retrieve the partial view...

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/controller/action/id',
    type:'GET',
    beforeSend: function(){
        //some loading indicator
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#dialog").html(data);
        $("#dialog").dialog({define some options});
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
    error: function(data)
        //handle error
    }


});
```

Your controller action can return your partial view. The ajax function will retrieve the data, update the page and then open the dialog. You can save some space here by combining some of these calls, but I was trying to be clear about the functionality.

One problem with your current code is that you're creating the div tag with jQuery, but I don't see where you actually write that out to the DOM ( with append, appendTo, etc...).

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
```

Comment: Ok.  I actually got it to work and load my partial view.  One thing that is weird though, is that I can't close it using the cancel button.  One of the windows closes, but there is apparently another window right beneath it that never closes.  Why is that happening?  Anybody every run into this?

Comment: No. I've never seen that happen. You may post the working code that you have into a new question. Link me to it and I'll try to help. It's just tough to say what's going on without seeing your code.